# why does std::map take a pair?

Tags: c++, stl

That syntax of:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 42));
```

seems a bit crazy.

Why is there no alternative `insert(K k, V v)` method which would provide a much saner:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m.insert(1, 42);
```

Yes, I'm aware of `m[1] = 42`, but it has its own problems (creating an extra copy of the value object).

Comment: `m.emplace(1, 42)`?

Comment: Consistency and history, I guess. I think `map` already worked like this in the original STL before it was incorporated into the standard library, and since the container's value type *is* a pair, using a pair as the parameter type is simply the most logical way. AFAIK, `operator[]` was an afterthought, designed as a (inconsistent) convenience function exactly to provide the "saner" alternative you are asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why that construct isn't allowed. Perhaps to keep `insert` similar to other containers' `insert` method. However, since c++11, there is [map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) that does what you want.

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m.emplace(1, 42);
```

Answer (score -2):

`m.insert(x, y);` forces a copy of the two parameters; whereas `m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 42));` allows the call to get a `const& pair` which avoids all copying. That way, `map` can contain uncopyable objects (or heavy-duty copy objects)

Comment: So creating a pair by `std::make_pair` does not lead to copying?

Comment: Quite the opposite, the `make_pair` approach encourages creation of incorrectly-typed pair object, which cannot be passed to `insert` directly and requires an extra conversion, i.e. an extra copy. Your example actually illustartes that popular mistake very well. Your `make_pair` will create an `<int, int>` pair, while `insert` requires a `<const int, int>` pair. The compiler will not complain because the former is implicitly convertible to the latter. But the conversion will create a temporary copy. So hello, unnecessary copying!

Comment: @AnT can you elaborate what is wrong with the make_pair in his example?  It is not const enough?

Comment: @MK. It has a type of `std::pair<int, int>` instead of `std::pair<const int, int>`.